# Ask Contact Picker to show a subset of contacts

Tags: android

I can use this code to trigger a Contact Picker to show a list of contacts so that I can pick one of them.

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_REQUEST);
```

However, how can I send my request to show part of contacts, such as the name beginning by "A" only?